# How to deal with shared modules in a micro-apps architecture

Tags: dart, micro-frontend

I've been looking at micro-app approaches for building applications in Flutter and I had questions about how to properly separate shared interface modules.

Given [this project](https://github.com/DeividWillyan/Micro-FrontEnds) as an example. It is separated into a base app, a home micro app, a login micro app, and a micro core. In this package, we have an abstract `class MicroApp` containing, as a definition, the name of the MicroApp and its corresponding routes.

Suppose now that we need to have a new micro app, root tabs shell, containing, for example, in the first tab, the "Home" micro app, and in a second tab, the "Profile" micro app. How would you achieve this?

The first and most obvious solution would be to simply expose widgets from these micro-packages, but then, I'd argue that we would be breaking MicroApp's encapsulation, so, I guess this is a non-go. So, I had some ideas:

First one would be to have a RouteDefinition and some sort of recursion. For example:

```dart
abstract class RouteDefinition {
  RouteDefinition({
    required this.builder,
    this.primary,
  });

  /// The identifier of the Primary Route.
  ///
  /// If null, this is considered a root route.
  String? primary;

  Widget Function(BuildContext context, Object? args) builder;
}

abstract class MicroApp {
  String get microAppName;

  Map<String, RouteDefinition> get routes;
}
```

Then one could simply recursively store all the secondary routes and pass them to its main route. However, I'm not sure if the MicroApp should know about the main app - passing a primary route to it means it should know it lies inside another MicroApp.